# How to hide child element clicking outside dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I can hide child element with add every child element this code:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
let children = parent[0].children[0]
if (event.target != children && event.target.parentNode != children){
    children.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

But how can hide child ul element clicking outside child ul element(with for loop or something else) without add this code every child element?

In this code I show child ul element when clicking parent li element

```js
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li');

parent[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
  parent[0].children[0].style.display = 'block';
});

parent[1].addEventListener('click', function () {
  parent[1].children[0].style.display = 'block';
});

parent[2].addEventListener('click', function () {
  parent[2].children[0].style.display = 'block';
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
  let children = parent[0].children[0]
 if (event.target != children && event.target.parentNode != children){
        children.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

ul, li {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>parent1
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent2
    <ul>
      <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent3
    <ul>
      <li>child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem: User clicks on any of the child elements, there should not be any change in the child state (hide). You can use the below code (I am assuming that you are using ES5 only). If you want to hide the child elements on parent click, then remove the `isParentClick()` method.

```js
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li');
    var len = parent.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       parent[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if(event.target !== event.currentTarget.children[0].children[0]){
            if(event.currentTarget.children[0].style.display === 'block'){
              event.currentTarget.children[0].style.display = 'none';
            } else {
              event.currentTarget.children[0].style.display = 'block';
            }
         }
            
     });
      }
    
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){  
      if(isParentClick()){
       return false;
      }
      
      if(isChildClick(event)){
       return false;
      }
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       parent[i].children[0].style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
    
    function isParentClick(){
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(parent[i] === event.target){
         return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    
    function isChildClick(event){
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(parent[i].children[0].children[0] === event.target){
         return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

ul, li {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>parent1
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent2
    <ul>
      <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>parent3
    <ul>
      <li>child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But how to make when click parent <li> again, hide child <ul>. For example click parent1 show child1 and when click again parent1 hide child1. Thanks

Comment: @GalibHasanov You can check the chid display state on click of the parent. Please check the updated code.

Comment: But now I click child then its hiding. How to avoid this?

Comment: Hmm. If we click on child, we are also triggering the parent click event. I put a condition in the updated codebase. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of targeting individual elements
Since to display the child the click will be on `li` so again do a `querySelector` and select `ul` and add the style.

Note use of `stopPropagation`.There is another event attached to `body` so that any click on `body` will hide the child. The usage of stopPropagation is to prevent the event from `bubling` phase the click on li and click on body both will happen simultaneously.

The body is bordered in red

```js
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('body > ul > li');

parent.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    
    item.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'block';
  })
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.parent').forEach(function(item) {
      item.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'none'
    })
  })
})
```

```css
ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

ul,
li {
  width: max-content;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='parent'>parent1
    <ul>
      <li>child1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='parent'>parent2
    <ul>
      <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='parent'>parent3
    <ul>
      <li>child3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But how can make when click parent <li> again, hide child <ul>. For example click parent1 show child1 and when click again parent1 hide child1.

Comment: @GalibHasanov take a look at `toggle`

Comment: I change code. Looks like it's working, but now when I click child element its hiding. http://jsfiddle.net/tr2uk9fs/3/